# Why does my binary tree deletion remove entire left portion of tree?

Tags: c, debugging, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have an assignment in which i need to make an implementation of a binary search tree in C. In my attempt of implementing a delete function for the tree i have failed to make an implementation that doesn't delete the entire (or almost entire) tree, if the node to be deleted is on the left side. This is the function i have written:

```
btree_node *btree_remove(const int x, btree_node *root) {
  //if the value cant be found return null;
   if (root == NULL) return root;
  //search for the node to be deleted
   if (x < root->data) {
    root->left = btree_remove(x, root->left);
   }
   
   if (x > root->data){
    root->right = btree_remove(x, root->right);
   }
   else {
    //case when there is no child
     if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL)) {
      free(root);
       return NULL;
     }
     //case when it has one child
     else {if (root->right == NULL){
        btree_node* temp = root->left;
        free(root);
        return temp;
      }
      if (root->left == NULL) {
        btree_node* temp = root->right;
        free(root);
        return temp;
      }
     }
      
      //case when it has two children
      if((root->left != NULL) && (root->right !=NULL)){
        btree_node* minNode = findMin(root->right);
        root->data = minNode->data;
        root->right = btree_remove(minNode->data, root->right);
        return root;
      }
   }
 }
```

A binary tree i have made using an insert function looks as such:

```
   10
  /  \
 5    17
/ \
2  NULL
```

When i then try to delete the node (5) the expected outcome is:

```
      10
     /  \
    2    17
   / \
NULL  NULL
```

The outcome using this function is:

```
      17
     /  \
    2    NULL
   / \
NULL  NULL
```

Comment: You forgot to show `findMin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `if` - `else if` - `else` structure. Currently, if `x < root->data` is true (and indeed, 5 < 17), then the first `if` will evaluate to `true`, `root->left` will be assigned to 5 (after the inner `btree_remove` is executed and evaluated) and then `x > root->data` will be false (because 5 > 5 is not true) and the `else` will be executed erroneously.

What you actually need is to differentiate `x < root->data` from `x > root->data` from `else` and, like the conditions, the blocks should be mutually exclusive too:

```
   if (x < root->data) {
    root->left = btree_remove(x, root->left);
   }
   
   else if (x > root->data){
    root->right = btree_remove(x, root->right);
   }
   else {
    //case when there is no child
     if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL)) {
      free(root);
       return NULL;
     }
     //case when it has one child
     else {if (root->right == NULL){
        btree_node* temp = root->left;
        free(root);
        return temp;
      }
      if (root->left == NULL) {
        btree_node* temp = root->right;
        free(root);
        return temp;
      }
     }
```